# KUKA error some robots are not mastered

Tags: java, kuka-krl, lbr-iiwa-rapi

I hope that anybody can help me with a KUKA iiwa.

I got the error message

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application execution is not
>   possible because some of the robots are not mastered."

on the smartPad.

I write the application with the KUKA sunrise Java API.

The error occurs when I try to run an application. Every changes that I have made since the error occurs, was restored but it changed nothing.

I hope somebody nows that kind of error.

Comment: Have you mastered the robot as suggested? I got this checklist, may be it helps:

- Switch the controller off.
- Disconnect robot.
- Switch the controller on.
- Move the robot to the vertical stretch position with the brake release device.
- Switch the controller off.
- Connect robot
- Switch the controller on.
- Reset robot position (see also LWR documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem whilst I turned the power off an reboot the robot. 
After the reboot I was able to master the axis of the robot which was not mastered and not displayed as unmastered.